# Tabbar not selected on notification

Tags: swift, storyboard, tabbar

I have a navigationVIewController as a rootViewController at one case and a viewController as a rootViewController in one case.

When the rootViewController is the viewController, i'm unable to show the viewController at that tabbar using the below code, in the didRecieveRemoteNotification method.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {      

    if let type = userInfo["type"] as! String! {
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive {

            if self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController != nil {
                //Works Fine
            } else {
                let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let myNavigationController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navBarID") as! UINavigationController
                let myTabbarController = myNavigationController.viewControllers[0] as! UITabBarController

                if type == "newsfeed" {
                    myTabbarController.selectedViewController = myTabbarController.viewControllers![3]
                } else if type == "event" {
                    myTabbarController.selectedViewController = myTabbarController.viewControllers![2]
                }                    
            }
        } else {
            // Foreground

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should select proper tab when the app is launched.Check out this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706455/open-app-in-specific-view-when-user-taps-on-push-notification-with-ios-swift

Comment: When my rootViewController is not the tabbarController, which is embedded in navigationController, i'm unable to select the needed tab.

Comment: did you try myTabbarController.selectedIndex?

Comment: also you are not changing root view controller anywhere. check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653993/programatically-change-rootviewcontroller-of-storyboard

Comment: Yes. I got it. I though that we cannot the change the rootViewController of an app after launching. Thank you!!