# Opening notification in a detailed controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I use FireBase in my project and i get notification with topic. As when clicking on the notification open and pass data to the detailed controller.

For example as in the BBC News program

it is storyBoard

[image]

```
import UIKit  
import UserNotifications  
import Firebase  
import FirebaseInstanceID  
import FirebaseMessaging  
import SystemConfiguration

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate , UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate{

var window: UIWindow?    

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "news")
    }

    FirebaseApp.configure()


    return true
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Refer This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706455/open-app-in-specific-view-when-user-taps-on-push-notification-with-ios-swift)

you need to redirect to your particular detailed view controller

Comment: In what function?  DidReceiveRemoteNotification?  And how to transfer data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706455/open-app-in-specific-view-when-user-taps-on-push-notification-with-ios-swift

Answer (score 0):

try This

add this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

if let notification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let aps = notification["aps"] as! [String : AnyObject]

        let storybaord = getStoryboardObject(storyboardName: "Main")as UIStoryboard
        let aboutUsObj = storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationViewController")as! NotificationViewController
        aboutUsObj.aps = aps
        let navigationController: UINavigationController? = (AppDelegate.getDelegate().window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(aboutUsObj, animated: true)
    }

    return true
}
```

add this code in AppDelegate Class

Get StoryBoardObject

```
func getStoryboardObject(storyboardName:String) -> UIStoryboard {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName as String, bundle: nil)

    return storyboard

}
```

Get AppdelegateObject

```
class func getDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```

Comment: you have used NavigationController as rootView Controller to use:

Comment: let navigationController: UINavigationController? = (AppDelegate.getDelegate().window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(aboutUsObj, animated: true)

Comment: otherwise use this :  let controller = AppDelegate.getDelegate().window?.rootViewController 
            controller?.present(aboutUsObj, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Value of type 'ViewControllerDetail' has no member 'aps'

Comment: you have add  var aps = [String: AnyObject]() in 'ViewControllerDetail'

Comment: Fixed but it does not go into viewcontrollerdetail

Comment: are you used NavigationController as rootView ?

Comment: Yes, i used navController as rootview

Comment: please try this     "let controller = AppDelegate.getDelegate().window?.rootViewController controller?.present(aboutUsObj, animated: true, completion: nil)"

Comment: The application crashes when you click on the notification